# Is there a way to pause FileVault encryption if it is in progress?

Tags: filevault

Is there a way to pause FileVault encryption if its in progress on APFS (NOT revert it or disable it, just put it on pause)?

P.S. I have researched this online and found the following post:

[is there a way to stop mac osx disk encryption in progress?](https://superuser.com/questions/461757/is-there-a-way-to-stop-mac-osx-disk-encryption-in-progress)

it does not have the answer that I am looking for.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: For what purpose?

Comment: Testing, need to make sure that encryption is complete before proceeding onto the next item.

Comment: or, rather not just complete but that its not in the stat of encrypting.