# Reverting a hard drive encryption process on Mac stuck on X percent

Tags: macos, hard-drive, encryption, time-machine, filevault

I have an external HDD used for both storage and Time Machine backups (by "storage" I mean non time-machine files are found on that HDD as well, outside of the "backups.backupdb" folder)

After not backing for months wanted to connect it but the Time Machine dropdown menu was saying it is encrypting the HDD. The number didn't change from 58% in over two hours.

Following up on [this](https://superuser.com/a/667734), I used the following:

> diskutil cs revert '/Volumes/WD Elements' -passphrase

After a reboot, when running `diskutil cs list` it says

```
Encryption Type:         AES-XTS
Encryption Status:       Unlocked
Conversion Status:       Converting (backward)
Reversion State:         Reverting
High Level Queries:      Not Fully Secure
```

and:

```
Disk:                  disk3
Status:                Online
Size (Total):          1999650029568 B (2.0 TB)
Conversion Progress:   42%
Revertible:            Yes (unlock and decryption required)
LV Name:               WD Elements
Volume Name:           WD Elements
```

However, the 42% also isn't changing at all. I rebooted once again and the number went up from 41%, but nothing changed since.

Is there a way for me to stop the process and just backup to this HDD? I have to take my Mac in for service tomorrow so I'd like to back it up before without having to lose all the other files I already on have on that external drive.

Comment: The drive is probably failing.

Comment: It's either failing or your patience was too short; which you exacerbated by then trying to undo what you didn't have the patience for it to do… I see now you are in between rock<>hard place. Wait it out [at least 24h] or wipe it & start afresh. Patience should now be directly proportional to the availability of your off-site backup.